# Search and Print a specific digit from a logfile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a **log.text** file with this structure:

```
user                session             login_time          application         database            db_connect_time     request             request_time        connection_source   connection_ip       request_state
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 admin                                 0                   9                                                           0 none                                  0 Not Requested*      a00:bf32::                    
 admin                         989855740                1335 DRRDEVMH            DRRPRODB                           1201 none                                  0 Not Requested       a00:8a45::                    
 admin                        1768947706                 932 test                test                                916 none                                  0 Not Requested       a00:94b6::                    

 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 1.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 9.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 WARNING - 1241024 - Possible string truncation in column 10.
 WARNING - 1241028 - Output column defined with warnings.
 OK/INFO - 1241044 - Records returned: [3].
```

As we can see in the last line of log.txt there is a string `Records returned: [3]`. That digit 3 is my target, extracting that digit (as 3 in this case) I want to print following line in a separate file.

```
The total records returned = 3
```

I am using:

```
sed -n 's@^.*Records returned.*[\(.*\)$@\1@p' log.txt > out.txt
```

but its not giving the result. What mistake I am making here, please ?

Comment: grep "Records returned:" | sed -n 's@^.*Records returned.*\[\(.*\)\].*$@\1@p' log.txt > out.txt

Comment: @Ashish..Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 37: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to escape `[`, try this one

```
sed -n 's@^.*Records returned.*\[\(.*\)\].*$@\1@p' log.txt > out.txt
```

**Edit**
If you want to print out the string like this

> The total records returned = 3

just prepend `The total records returned =` before `\1`, so the script will be

```
sed -n 's@^.*Records returned.*\[\(.*\)\].*$@The total records returned = \1@p' log.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Does only print the number `3` and not the desired text.

Comment: From the original post `sed -n 's@^.*Records returned.*[\(.*\)$@\1@p' log.txt`, he was not printing the string `The total records returned = `, so I left out the string also.  I edited my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F "[][]" '$0~t  {print "The total",t,"=",$2}' t="Records returned" log.txt > out.txt
cat out.txt    
The total Records returned = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '$ s/.*\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)].$/The total records returned = \1/p'
```

Assuming, as your sample and explaination state, that info is on the last line with this format.

Comment: Sorry but its not working.there is nothing coming in out.txt.

Comment: wich sed/os are you using (I test on my AIX/KSH and it works), if GNU sed try to add --posix parameter

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Your Data in a Test.txt file then You can simply use below Command

```
echo "Total Records Count = `cat Test.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d '[' -f2 | cut -d ']' -f1` "
```

Total Records Count = 3

[image]

Comment: Hmmm , i have tested on Redhat 6 and its working fine. Added screen shot . Hoping you replaced the file name Test.txt with your data file name(log.txt or ***).